# Uploading image after image and displaying them all

Tags: php, json, image-uploading

I've already asked a couple of questions regarding this and each step gets me closer however it still doesnt work as intended.

I want to upload an image and write it to the textfile, then when i upload another image that will be written to the end and so on so forth. So ultimately you'll have a long file with lots of images.

As far as i can tell my code should work but it doesn't. Here is a link to the site [website for testing](http://wonx.dk/imgUploader/). Testing it maybe useful and below is the code.

It also always creates an empty element at the end of the array as you'll see from testing the site.

The PHP:

```
$sFileName = "imgDB.txt";

for ($i=0 ; $i < count($_FILES) ; $i++) {
    move_uploaded_file(
        $_FILES['file-'.$i]['tmp_name'],
        "img/". $_FILES['file-'.$i]['name']
    );
}

$sImgs = file_get_contents($sFileName); //gets a string from the file.

if (json_decode($sImgs, true) != false) {
    $ajImgs = json_decode($sImgs, true);
} else {
    $ajImgs = array();
}

$aOutPut = array_merge ($ajImgs, $_FILES);

$aSendToFile = json_encode(
    $aOutPut,
    JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE
);
file_put_contents($sFileName, $aSendToFile);
```

Comment: The link you provided, to http://wonx.dk/imgUploaderas, is not working

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I've fixed it :).

Answer (score 1):

Some remarks

- if the `move_uploaded_file` call is not protected further, this allows to upload any files, including script files - this opens a security vulnerability in your application - check for MIME-type and file-extension to avoid this
- `json_decode` returns `null` if the input value is empty or cannot be decoded - not `false` like in your code
- appending to an array is not done with `array_merge`, this just overrides the properties of `$_FILES` of the previous execution - use `$aOutPut[] = $_FILES;` instead